# Rails project won't start - error unexpected : expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to get ribbot an open source code from [this git repository](http://git://github.com/barmstrong/ribbot.git). I have already downloaded rails and its necessary gems, as well as mongo db and have "bundle installed".
However I get the following error when running the project.

How can this be solved?

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /Users/hansarijanto/Desktop/Impact/ribbot/config/initializers/session_store.rb:4:
>
> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
>       ...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_ribbot_session', :domain =>...

I have traced the file with the syntax error which is session_store.rb which currently looks like this:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# See environment specific overrides also
Ribbot::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_ribbot_session', :domain => :all, :expire_after => 10.years

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
# Ribbot::Application.config.session_store :active_record_sto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since ribbot is using ruby 1.9 you should update your ruby version, rather than change the code to make it work, the current ruby version is 1.9.3
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

install instructions

- if you're using mac OS:

http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

- if you're using ubuntu linux:

http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10-4148.html

- if you're using windows:
  http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 3):

You're using Ruby 1.8 but are using [Ruby 1.9 hash syntax](http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-1-9-and-the-new-hash-syntax) in your `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. The following snippet:

```
key: '_ribbot_session'
```

should be

```
:key => '_ribbot_session'
```

Comment: I have tried that but still get this error while running:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /Users/hansarijanto/Desktop/Impact/ribbot/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]

Comment: @HansAdiputraArijanto That's a completely different file, but it may be the same issue. Check that file and see if it also uses Ruby 1.9 hash syntax and, if so, replace it in the same manner as in my answer.

Comment: Would it be more beneficial if i just updated my ruby to 1.9?

Comment: sorry seems like im running 1.8.7 which is not desireable apparently. Do you have any recommendation as to how I should update my version? I  would like to avoid version conflicts.

Comment: @HansAdiputraArijanto Have a look at [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io//), which are two popular tools for managing Ruby versions.